# codeigniter: pagination + table libraries (not working)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I need help on my code igniter app..i can't seem to find out what's causing the pagination not to work

**here's my controller**

```
$limit = 15;
        $uri_segment = 4;
        $this->load->helper('string');

        $offset = $this->uri->segment( $uri_segment );
        log_message('error',date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
        //load
        //$products = $this->Products_model->get_all();
        $products = $this->Products_model->get_products($limit, $uri_segment);
        //var_dump($products);

        log_message('error', $products );

        //pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/products/index/');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Products_model->count_all();
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        //table
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;");
        $this->table->set_heading('ID', 'Product','Category', 'Actions');
        $i = 0 + $offset;
        foreach ($products as $product){
            ++$i;
            $this->table->add_row($product->id, $product->title, $this->Categories_model->get_by_id($product->category_id)->title,
                anchor('/admin/products/update/'.$product->id,'update',array('class'=>'update')).' '.
                anchor('/admin/products/delete/'.$product->id,'delete',array('class'=>'delete','onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this product?')"))
            );
        }
        $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();

        //load template
        $this->products_list();
        $this->products_template();
        $this->template->build('products/productList', $data);
```

**here's my model**

```
function get_products($num, $offset) {
    return $this->db->get($this->tbl_products, $num, $offset)->result();    
}
```

it generates the links but then it doesn't load the next set of records..any corrections on the code above?

thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the pagination library just generates the links for you, it's up to you to pass the offset and limit to your model's get() function (or whatever you call it).

Comment: Exactly, look at get_where, it has what you would need.

Comment: can you please give me a hint or sample? im just new into php programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the page to the table, not the full table. Pagination just fills the links, but doesn't make any change on your data, it's your responsability.

Please change:

```
        $products = $this->Products_model->get_all();
```

with:

```
        $products = $this->Products_model->get_page( $Offset, $this->limit ); // It's not clear where do you define limit.
```

and in your model make the propper selection:

```
function get_page( $offset, $limit ){
    return $this->db->get( $this->tbl_products, $limit, $offset )->result();
}
```

Comment: hi, i have updated my code just like what you suggest..but then it doesn't load the next set of records

Comment: please check the value of 'offset' in the pagination links. Can you give me the # of records and the 'limit' value? It's not clear in your code

Comment: you wrote '$products = $this->Products_model->get_products($limit, $uri_segment);', change '$uri_segment' by '$offset'

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your limit($this->limit) has good data (only integers). If you have query string turned on you may get the string '&per_page=' passed onto your model. If so clean $this->limit with a regular expression or str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your error

```
$products = $this->Products_model->get_products($limit, $uri_segment);

$limit=the number of data you want to show in per page,

$offset=the data number start from.
```

So click on per link you have to change the offset value to show the data. try this

```
if($this->uri->segment(uri_segment) > 0){

                $offset=$this->uri->segment($uri_segment);

            }
            else{
                $offset=0;

            }
$products = $this->Products_model->get_products($limit, $offset);
```